# The exact syntax of Velocity Template in IDEA Copyright Profile

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

*IntelliJ IDEA* has a convenient feature which can maintain copyright comments in your code, via the [*Update Copyright*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright.html) action.

Yet, the documentation is scarce and barely covers one single use-case.

The question is, what is the exact signature (and behaviour) of the `${originalComment.match()}` function? Looking at the *Velocity* template language [documentation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html), there's no standard `match()` function.

Looking at the only example provided by *JetBrains*:

```
$originalComment.match("Copyright \(c\) (\d+)", 1, "-")
```

- the 1st argument is the regular expression per se,
- the 2nd one (`1`) is probably the number of the RE capturing group to extract, and
- the last one (`"-"`) is the [suffix](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/copyright/src/com/maddyhome/idea/copyright/pattern/CommentInfo.java#L39) to be appended to the extracted RE group value.

Yet, after some testing, the behaviour of the function seems counter-intuitive.

My own use case:

1. New files should have `Copyright (c) 2024-2024` as their copyright statement.
2. `Copyright (c) 1970` should get updated to `Copyright (c) 1970-2024`.
3. `Copyright (c) 1970-1971` → `Copyright (c) 1970-2024`.
4. `Copyright (c) 2024` → `Copyright (c) 2024-2024`.
5. `Copyright (c) 2024-2024` should remain intact on update.

What my *Velocity* template should look like?

The closest I could get to the solution is

```
Copyright (c) My Company ${originalComment.match("Copyright \([Cc]\) .+ (\d{4})(?:\-\d{4})?", 1, "-")}${today.year}.
```

— but, obviously, it doesn't work for new code (**Item 1** is not covered) and, strangely, **Item 4** doesn't work, either (despite I'm not using any [ignore values](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/copyright/src/com/maddyhome/idea/copyright/pattern/CommentInfo.java#L39)).

Comment: This template covers cases 2-5: 
"Copyright (c) $originalComment.match("Copyright \(c\) (\d+)", 1, "-")$today.year. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ".
To cover case 1 you need to run "Update Copyright" action after creating file and it will change 2024 to 2024-2024